tabularray repeatrow
i try to make some kind of table, where i create a number of rows automatically.
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{german} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} % Paket für Kopf- und Fußzeilen 
\usepackage{pgffor} % Paket für Schleifen



%\ohead{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{c:/Schule/logo_rot_3.jpg}}
\ifoot{08.02.2024}

%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.1}
\newcommand{\createTable}[1]{
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec = {|Q[5,l]|Q[3,c]|Q[2,c]|Q[2,c]|}, % Gleichmäßige Verteilung der Spalten
            row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c}, % Formatierung der ersten Zeile
            hlines, % Horizontale Linien
            vlines, % Vertikale Linien
            width=\textwidth % Breite der Tabelle auf Textbreite setzen
        }
        Kurs / Klasse & Raum & Anzahl & Vollständig? (abhaken) \\
        Beispiel: Physik Q3 & Starck & P1 & 17 & \checkmark \\
        \foreach \i in {1,...,#1} { & & & \\ }
    \end{tblr}
    }
    
    \begin{document}
        \section{Schulhof Altbau}
        \begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{l X}
            Räume & 005, 007, 008, 106, 107, 108, 109, 111, 113, 206, 207, 208, 209, 211, 214, 304, 305, 306, 307, 311\\
        \end{tabularx}\\
        \createTable{5}     

\end{document}

Leads to "undefined control sequence".
The documentation says something like that, i do not have enough experience to integrate it. Can you help me?
\IgnoreSpacesOn
 \prgNewFunction \makeEmptyTable {mm}  {
  \tlSet \lTmpaTl {\intReplicate {\intEval{#2-1}} {&}}
  \tlPutRight \lTmpaTl {\\}
  \intReplicate {#1} {\tlUse \lTmpaTl}
 }
 \IgnoreSpacesOff
 \begin{tblr}[evaluate=\makeEmptyTable]{hlines,vlines}
  \makeEmptyTable{3}{7}
 \end{tblr}


You can build the repeated rows beforehand and then expand the created command.
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{german} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} % Paket für Kopf- und Fußzeilen 

\usepackage{amssymb}


%\ohead{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{c:/Schule/logo_rot_3.jpg}}
\ifoot{08.02.2024}

\newcommand{\createTable}[1]{%
  \repeatrow{#1}{ & & & \\ }%
  \begin{tblr}[
    expand=\repeatedrow
  ]{
    colspec = {|Q[5,l]|Q[3,c]|Q[2,c]|Q[2,c]|}, % Gleichmäßige Verteilung der Spalten
    row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c}, % Formatierung der ersten Zeile
    hlines, % Horizontale Linien
    vlines, % Vertikale Linien
    width=\textwidth % Breite der Tabelle auf Textbreite setzen
  }
  Kurs / Klasse & Raum & Anzahl & Vollständig? (abhaken) \\
  Beispiel: Physik Q3 & Starck & P1 & 17 & \checkmark \\
  \repeatedrow
  \end{tblr}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\repeatrow}{mm}
 {
  \tl_set:Ne \repeatedrow { \prg_replicate:nn {#1} {#2} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Schulhof Altbau}

\createTable{5}     

\end{document}


